ggplot line plots are not showing up on proportional secondary axis
I am trying to plot a barplot, and overlay some plots onto it using a secondary axis. I am able to adjust the secondary axis to be proportional to the values but the line plots still seem be squished at the bottom.
Here is my code and data:
library(ggplot)
library(tidyr)

> dput(dsr1)
structure(list(Site = c("DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DR", "DR", "DR", 
"DR", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "MR", "MR", 
"MR", "MR"), Gene = c("dsr", "dsr", "dsr", "dsr", "dsr", "dsr", 
"dsr", "dsr", "dsr", "dsr", "dsr", "dsr", "dsr", "dsr", "dsr", 
"dsr", "dsr", "dsr", "dsr", "dsr"), Var = c("Sep", "Nov", "Dec", 
"Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", 
"Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan"), Avg = c(26192.15213, 
1060.62995, 5976.49445, 18627.35088, 9230.00425, 8154.795375, 
15599.3215, 33674.06525, 5375.773538, 1243.98395, 1368.094813, 
18126.26463, 11128.72975, 3512.390263, 15628.89188, 12514.475, 
10136.56213, 10330.751, 15907.58675, 21435.79538), Std = c(1971.846094, 
80.20201232, 1492.776454, 1716.348126, 1312.541508, 682.2806779, 
3751.417264, 1518.661188, 1035.91546, 169.1677183, 68.78619696, 
1653.659567, 3832.856982, 218.6107193, 650.6329325, 3516.620678, 
2528.207035, 451.3704901, 907.4479828, 550.5151197)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

> dput(srb1)
structure(list(Site = c("DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", 
"DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", 
"DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", 
"DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", 
"DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DR", "DR", "DR", 
"DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", 
"DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", 
"DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", 
"DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", "DR", 
"DR", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", 
"FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", 
"FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", 
"FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", 
"FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", 
"FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", 
"FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", 
"FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", 
"FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "MR", "MR", 
"MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", 
"MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", 
"MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", 
"MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", "MR", 
"MR", "MR"), SRB = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "G", "G", "G", "G", "H", "H", "H", "H", "I", "I", 
"I", "I", "J", "J", "J", "J", "K", "K", "K", "K", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E", "F", "F", "F", "F", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "H", "H", "H", "H", "I", "I", "I", "I", "J", "J", 
"J", "J", "K", "K", "K", "K", "L", "L", "L", "L", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "F", "F", "F", "F", "G", "G", "G", "G", "H", 
"H", "H", "H", "I", "I", "I", "I", "J", "J", "J", "J", "K", "K", 
"K", "K", "L", "L", "L", "L", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "G", "G", "G", "G", "H", "H", "H", "H", "I", 
"I", "I", "I", "J", "J", "J", "J", "K", "K", "K", "K", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "H", "H", "H", "H", "I", "I", "I", "I", "J", 
"J", "J", "J", "K", "K", "K", "K", "L", "L", "L", "L"), Var = c("Sep", 
"Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", 
"Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", 
"Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", 
"Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", 
"Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", 
"Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", 
"Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", 
"Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", 
"Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", 
"Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", 
"Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", 
"Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", 
"Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", 
"Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", 
"Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", 
"Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", 
"Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", 
"Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", 
"Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", 
"Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", 
"Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", 
"Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", 
"Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", 
"Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", 
"Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", 
"Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", 
"Jan", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan"), Avg = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.003854866, 
0.061106412, 0.071682456, 0.00059896, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.098315511, 0, 0.004801973, 0.063737569, 1.964397117, 
0.145974324, 0.155585996, 2.021656134, 0.144172778, 0.039715264, 
0.072734409, 0.277671026, 0.395869671, 0.094600576, 0.416784381, 
0.509686627, 0.002391391, 0, 0, 0.01107881, 0.01776674, 0, 0.010330774, 
0.116655538, 0.019222751, 0.048718956, 0.003774214, 0.048769952, 
0.000404064, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000808129, 0.025281279, 0.000935706, 
0.007744674, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.024454972, 0.026716446, 
0.010346329, 0.031761494, 0.176511803, 0.002071508, 0, 0.004252813, 
0.022717954, 0.044868941, 0.017135875, 0.02262901, 0.204066738, 
0.061230801, 0.07198863, 0.190769924, 0.000673709, 0, 0, 0, 0.019986705, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.013240102, 0.006850463, 
0.007235685, 0.014429782, 0.001452608, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.056095432, 
0.00906202, 0.003799885, 0.018233616, 0.120468519, 0.001127625, 
0.005593377, 0.007697997, 0.116444276, 0.060955479, 0.027829322, 
0.059367186, 0.232145552, 0.02543649, 0.089065429, 0.08453107, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.015783104, 0, 0, 0.001603001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.008758482, 0.005594702, 0.013502405, 0.010478338, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.009879588, 0.005346856, 0.016387101, 
0.012409584, 0.001962154, 0.001734556, 0, 0.007286852, 0.032146728, 
0.014142999, 0.047512303, 0.025582156, 0.122754967, 0.019880746, 
0.142894055, 0.158862745, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000797048, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.002049933, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00742221, 0, 0.007622556, 
0.017323055, 0.002210342, 0.00431524, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.027315991, 0.062928107, 0.014127331, 0.026469388, 0, 0.001349002, 
0.087496432, 0.00255964, 0.03077342, 0.054161156, 0.036458083, 
0.024667621, 0.166278721, 0.16856285, 0.167405409, 0.163786308, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.005834094, 0.002711961, 0, 0, 0, 0.009848701, 
0), Std = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.004489104, 0.101688894, 0.064949287, 
0.00119792, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.07991923, 0, 0.008036531, 
0.10050744, 1.697626013, 0.050273793, 0.192288778, 1.475742817, 
0.084535326, 0.021019687, 0.078525424, 0.14633414, 0.44279092, 
0.077102705, 0.774390338, 0.259203849, 0.004782782, 0, 0, 0.012875964, 
0.025904929, 0, 0.014403465, 0.194281549, 0.013769571, 0.04968971, 
0.004797693, 0.019973095, 0.000808129, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.001616257, 
0.006575046, 0.001871412, 0.001771095, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.016365279, 0.01172175, 0.008458564, 0.00480104, 0.353023607, 
0.004143017, 0, 0.005034407, 0.011968923, 0.017255941, 0.016173283, 
0.004738345, 0.09921792, 0.015230554, 0.053297221, 0.0894813, 
0.001347418, 0, 0, 0, 0.039973411, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.009959679, 0.011114534, 0.008731848, 0.011138718, 
0.002905215, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.047973853, 0.007723351, 0.005046906, 
0.007643438, 0.097174061, 0.002255249, 0.011186755, 0.005347923, 
0.043569938, 0.0436422, 0.015534005, 0.039596993, 0.144497391, 
0.022316042, 0.051071736, 0.030856551, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.019935073, 
0, 0, 0.003206002, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.007767112, 
0.007440585, 0.010550983, 0.009268475, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.00909171, 0.007409357, 0.008755822, 0.014391853, 0.003924308, 
0.003469112, 0, 0.006015714, 0.010585435, 0.006256366, 0.042498882, 
0.009395162, 0.090393123, 0.011347959, 0.116478044, 0.091113074, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.001594095, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.002434431, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.014844419, 0, 0.008804914, 0.006774488, 0.002575667, 
0.005594923, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.019338184, 0.058467452, 
0.007963778, 0.028527808, 0, 0.002698003, 0.174992863, 0.005119279, 
0.017470551, 0.032819923, 0.037334218, 0.013764006, 0.122531556, 
0.165503776, 0.194704629, 0.085870127, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.009423796, 
0.005423922, 0, 0, 0, 0.019697402, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -240L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

###keeping the order of my Var variables
dsr1$Var <- factor(dsr1$Var,levels=unique(dsr1$Var))
srb1$Var <- factor(srb1$Var,levels=unique(srb1$Var))

###bar plot
dsr_plot = ggplot(dsr1, aes(x = Var, y = Avg, ymin = Avg-Std, ymax = Avg+Std, fill = Site)) + 
    facet_wrap(~Site, ncol = 5) +
    geom_bar(colour = "black", stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.65, alpha = 0.8) +
    geom_errorbar(colour = "black", stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.65), width = 0.4) + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 16, angle = 90, vjust = 0.25), 
          axis.text.y = element_text(size = 16),
          panel.spacing.y = unit(1, "lines")) + 
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
dsr_plot

###adding the line plots
dsr_plot + geom_line(data = srb1, aes(x = Var, y = Avg, colour = SRB, group = SRB), size = 1) + 
    geom_point(data = srb1, size = 3, aes(colour = SRB)) + 
    geom_errorbar(data = srb1, aes(ymin = Avg - Std, ymax = Avg + Std, width = 0.25, colour = SRB), size = 0.5) + 
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans= ~./1000, name = "SRB (%)")) + 
    theme(legend.position = "top", legend.justification = "right",
          legend.text = element_text(size = 16),
          legend.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"),
          axis.title.y.right = element_text(margin = margin(l = 15))) + guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 4)))


As you can see, the line plots seem to be squished down at the bottom even though I've scaled my secondary y-axis down so that it is proportional to the values scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans= ~./1000, name = "SRB (%)")) 
I came across this post and this post which seems to be having the same issue and tried the solutions there but the plots still look the same even though the secondary y-axis scales changes.
Thanks in advance.

you have to apply the inverse transform to the data as well. So if you are creating a secondary axis by dividing by 1000, you have to multiple by 1000 when passing y to aes().  So, try aes(y=Avg*1000, ...) when calling geom_line() and geom_point() with srb1 data.  You might also find that 1000 is not quite the right multiplier, because your Avg values are all much lower than the 0,10,20,30 range that your current secondary axis provides. Perhaps try 10,000.

This worked. Thank you!

You need to apply the inverse transfrom to the data. So, if you are creating a secondary axis by dividing by 1000, you need to multiply by 1000 when passing y to aes(). So you can try this alternative in your geom_line() and geom_point() calls with srb1 data.
geom_<XXX>(data=srb1, aes(y=Avg*1000, ...))

